# for await, 2 варианта. Одно ли это и тоже?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
for await (test of promiseArray) {
  await test()
}

for await (test of promiseArray) {
  test()
}
```

Это одно и тоже (логика исполнения)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишем-ка тестовый скрипт:

```js
const sleep = (timeout = 500) => new Promise((resolve) =>
         setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), timeout));

(async() => {

  for (test of [sleep(), sleep()]) {
    const res = await test;
    console.log('part1', res);
  }

  for await (test of [sleep(), sleep(), 'lalala']) {
    console.log('part2', test);
  }

})();
```

> Выражение for await...of создаёт цикл, проходящий через асинхронные
> итерируемые объекты, а также синхронные итерируемые сущности,
> включающие: встроенные String, Array, Array-подобные объекты
> (например., arguments или NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, а также
> определяемые пользователем асинхронные/синхронные сущности. Он
> вызывает пользовательский итерационный хук с инструкциями, которые
> должны быть выполнены для значения каждого отдельного свойства
> объекта.

Comment: в вопросе в обоих примерах `for await of`. А что должен показать твой пример в ответе?

Comment: @Grundy думаю, топикстактер не подразумевал первый по счёту await в первом своём примере цикла